# Raspberry Pi 3 Python and Opencv for facial recognition

Tags: python, c++, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am receiving this message when trying to execute script whether in virtual environment or a normal Python shell.

```
File "/home/pi/facesample1.py", line 10, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:8000: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor
```

Here is my code:

```
import cv2

#Load an image from file
image = cv2.imread("fronthead.jpg", 1)

#Load a cascade file for detecting faces
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/usr/share/opencv/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

#Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Look for faces in the image using the loaded cascade file
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

print "Found "+str(len(faces))+" face(s)"

#Draw a rectangle around every found face
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

#Save the result image
cv2.imwrite('camresult.jpg',image)
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `image` variable is apparently not a 3 or 4 channel image.
Thus, `cvtColor()` is unable to transform it to grayscale.

Check `image.shape` and see that it returns something with the right dimensions (i.e. a 3D array with last dimension 3 or 4).

It is also quite possible that `image` is `None`, which usually means that the path to the file is wrong.

Comment: Thanks dude. I hadn't specified the full drive when loading the image.